# Is it possible to get another thread's print content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I will execute two methods `get` and `post` at the same time in diffrent threads, the first method `get` will last for a long time(100 seconds), and the second request `post` will repeat every 5 seconds. Here `get` request will print a lot as follow

```
import time
def get():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

What `post` need to do is to collect all the print content from `get` and **append** to a txt every time it executes(if file exists, add new contents to txt). Here is the pseudocode.

```
def post(request):
    print_from_get = sys.stdout
    with open("output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(print_from_get)
```

My question is whether we can collect the print from `get`, if possible, how should I do it?

Comment: You should set `sys.stdout` to an `io.StringIO` stream.

Comment: ``print`` is just the wrong tool for the job – ``stdout`` is purely intended as an *output* stream. Instead of trying to hack the ``stdout`` for something it's not meant to do, use a ``queue.Queue`` or similar.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi queue is of course a better solution, question is I have to import my colleague's code and they have prints in their code also. `post` have to collect all the print content include external packages.

Comment: @Barmar can you write it as an answer by `threading`

Comment: I would have a talk with the coworker first to determine if they should be using `print`, or if they should switch to using a queue.

Answer (score 0):

I present at the end a way for doing what is requested  but I do not recommend using bare `prints` for this. There are better tools, and if you still want to stick with `print`, you can use the `file` keyword to specify where the output should go.

```py
import time
import sys 

def get(out_stream=sys.stdout):
    for i in range(100):
        print(i, file=out_stream)
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

you can pass a file object opened with `open` as the argument, and the output will go to that file. Alternatively, you can use a `io.StringIO` as @barmar suggested, and write the contents to a file once `get` finishes.

All other options mess with `sys.stdout`, that is the default file object that `print` uses (it is the default value of the `file` keyword argument). This affects everything that uses `sys.stdout`, which can be more than all the `print` statements that get executed.

If you *need* to redirect bare `print` statements (not using `print`'s `file` keyword), you must replace `sys.stdout`. The most obvious replacement would be to use an output file object:

```py
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys

def get():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    with open("output.txt", "a") as text_fil:
        sys.stdout = text_fil
        get_thread = Thread(None, get)
        get_thread.start()
        get_thread.join()
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

If you need to have one writing thread and a reading thread, exactly as the question states, you can use Queues, but a simpler approach uses pipes (I added a dummy thread (`postthread`) that calls `post` to make it similar to OP's use):

```py
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys
import os

def get():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

def post(read_pipe):
    with open("output.txt", "ab") as text_fil:  # os.read yields bytes
        try:
            data = os.read(read_pipe, 65535)  # arbitrary (but large) number
            text_fil.write(data)
        except Exception as e:
            return True  # the read descriptor was closed: quit
    return len(data) == 0  # the write descriptor was closed: quit

def postthread(read_pipe):
    for _ in range(21):
        time.sleep(5)
        if post(read_pipe):
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    r_fd, w_fd = os.pipe()
    with os.fdopen(w_fd, 'wt') as write_pipe: # write pipe is a file object
        read_pipe = r_fd
        sys.stdout = write_pipe
        get_thread = Thread(None, get)
        post_thread = Thread(None, postthread, args=(read_pipe, ))
        post_thread.start()
        get_thread.start()
        get_thread.join()
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        # closing the write pipe (and its file descriptor) causes read to see EOF.
    post_thread.join()
    os.close(r_fd)
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
```